# Write XML data to CSV file in Java

Tags: java, xml, maven, csv, jaxb

I'm using a Maven project in netbeans 8.0.2 to read an XML file. The template of the xml file has been added as a dependency in the settings.xml file of the project. I'm able to read the file and print it's output successfully in the console using JAXB. I want to write the same console output in an CSV file. Please help

Java Code...

```
   private static void PUE_Checker(String fileName) {
    try {
        //Unmarshall the DDF File
        ElementDefinitionPackage elementDefinitionPackage = unmarshall(fileName);
        //For Each Element Definition Model Defined in Package Check If PUE Rules are defined in Datapoint Section and Rules Section
        for (ElementDefinitionModel model : elementDefinitionPackage.getElementDefinitionModels()) {
            //Check in Datapoints for Each Supported Protocol
            for (SupportedProtocolType supportedProtocol : model.getSupportedprotocols().getSupportedProtocols()) {
                boolean powerConsumedDataPointFound = false;
                boolean energyIntervalDataPointFound = false;
                for (DatapointType datapoint : supportedProtocol.getDatapoints().getDatapoints()) {
                    if (datapoint.getProgrammaticName().equalsIgnoreCase(PWR_CONSUMED_DP)) {
                        powerConsumedDataPointFound = true;
                    }
                    if (datapoint.getProgrammaticName().equalsIgnoreCase(ENRG_INTERVAL_DP)) {
                        energyIntervalDataPointFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!powerConsumedDataPointFound && !energyIntervalDataPointFound) {
                    System.out.println(" Both PUE Data point not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol() + " and Protocol: " + supportedProtocol.getProtocolName()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
                }else
                if (!powerConsumedDataPointFound) {
                    System.out.println("Power Consumed PUE Data point not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol() + " and Protocol: " + supportedProtocol.getProtocolName()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
                }else
                    if (!energyIntervalDataPointFound) {
                    System.out.println("Energy Interval PUE Data point not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol() + " and Protocol: " + supportedProtocol.getProtocolName()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
                }
            }
            // Check in Rules Section
            boolean powerConsumedRuleFound = false;
            boolean energyIntervalRuleFound = false;
            for (Rule rulesType : model.getRules().getRules()) {
                if (rulesType.getCollection() != null) {
                    if (rulesType.getCollection().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(PWR_CONSUMED_RULE)) {
                        powerConsumedRuleFound = true;
                    }
                    if (rulesType.getCollection().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ENRG_INTERVAL_RULE)) {
                        energyIntervalRuleFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!powerConsumedRuleFound && !energyIntervalRuleFound) {
                System.out.println("Both PUE Rules line not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
            }else 
            if (!powerConsumedRuleFound) {
                System.out.println("Power Consumed PUE Rule line not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
            }else
            if (!energyIntervalRuleFound) {
                System.out.println("Energy Interval PUE Rules line not defined for Model: " + model.getModelInSymbol() + ", Model Qualifier: " + model.getModelQualifierInSymbol()+ ", Symbol Tag: " + model.getSymbolTag());
            }
        }
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static ElementDefinitionPackage unmarshall(String file) throws JAXBException {
    return (ElementDefinitionPackage) JAXBContext.newInstance(ElementDefinitionPackage.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File(file));
}
```

Current Output:

```
   Both PUE Data point not defined for Model: AC500-ECO, Model Qualifier: PM564-R-AC and Protocol: MODBUS/RS-485, Symbol Tag: ABBAC500-ECOPM564-R-AC
   Both PUE Data point not defined for Model: AC500-ECO, Model Qualifier: PM564-R-AC and Protocol: MODBUS/TCP, Symbol Tag: ABBAC500-ECOPM564-R-AC
   Both PUE Rules line not defined for Model: AC500-ECO, Model Qualifier: PM564-R-AC, Symbol Tag: ABBAC500-ECOPM564-R-AC
```

Desired Output:

[image: CSV file]

Comment: I'd consider using something like [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), but that's because I'm lazy...